# Multithread+Recursion strategies

Tags: multithreading, recursion

I am just starting to learn the ins-and-outs of multithread programming and have a few basic questions that, once answered, should keep me occupied for quite sometime.  I understand that multithreading loses its effectiveness once you have created more threads than there are cores (due to context switching and cache flushing).  With that understood, I can think of two ways to employ multithreading of a recursive function...but am not quite sure what is the common way to approach the problem.  One seems much more complicated, perhaps with a higher payoff...but thats what I hope you will be able to tell me.

Below is pseudo-code for two different methods of multithreading a recursive function.  I have used the terminology of merge sort for simplicity, but it's not that important.  It is easy to see how to generalize the methods to other problems.  Also, I will personally be employing these methods using the `pthreads` library in `C`, so the thread syntax mildly reflects this.

Method 1:

```
main () 
{
    A = array of length N
    NUM_CORES = get number of functional cores
    chunk[NUM_CORES] = array of indices partitioning A into (N / NUM_CORES) sized chunks

    thread_id[NUM_CORES] = array of thread id’s
    thread[NUM_CORES] = array of thread type

    //start NUM_CORES threads on working on each chunk of A
    for i = 0 to (NUM_CORES - 1) {
        thread_id[i] = thread_start(thread[i], MergeSort, chunk[i])
    }

    //wait for all threads to finish
    //Merge chunks appropriately

    exit
}

MergeSort ( chunk ) 
{
    MergeSort ( lowerSubChunk )
    MergeSort ( higherSubChunk )

    Merge(lowerSubChunk, higherSubChunk)
}

//Merge(,) not shown
```

Method 2:

```
main () 
{
    A = array of length N
    NUM_CORES = get number of functional cores
    chunk = indices 0 and N

    thread_id[NUM_CORES] = array of thread id’s
    thread[NUM_CORES] = array of thread type

    //lock variable aka mutex
    THREADS_IN_USE = 1

    MergeSort( chunk )

    exit
}

MergeSort ( chunk )
{
    lock THREADS_IN_USE
    if ( THREADS_IN_USE < NUM_CORES ) {
        FREE_CORE = find index of unused core
        thread_id[FREE_CORE] = thread_start(thread[FREE_CORE], MergeSort, lowerSubChunk)
        THREADS_IN_USE++
        unlock THREADS_IN_USE
        MergeSort( higherSubChunk )

        //wait for thread_id[FREE_CORE] and current thread to finish

        lock THREADS_IN_USE
        THREADS_IN_USE--
        unlock THREADS_IN_USE

        Merge(lowerSubChunk, higherSubChunk)
    } 
    else {
        unlock THREADS_IN_USE
        MergeSort( lowerSubChunk )
        MergeSort( higherSubChunk )

        Merge(lowerSubChunk, higherSubChunk)
    }
}

//Merge(,) not shown
```

Visually, one can think of the differences between these two methods as follows:

Method 1: creates `NUM_CORES` separate recursion trees, each one having a single core traversing it.

Method 2: creates a single recursion tree but has all cores traversing it.  In particular, whenever there is a free core, it is set to work on the "left child subtree" of the first node where `MergeSort` is called after the core is freed.

The problem with Method 1 is that if it is the case that the running time of the recursive function varies with the distribution of values within each initial subchunk (i.e. the `chunk[i]`), one thread could finish much faster leaving a core sitting idle while the others finish.  With Merge Sort this is not likely to be the case since the work of `MergeSort` happens in `Merge` whose runtime isn't affected much by the distribution of values in the (sorted) subchunks.  However, with a more involved recursive function, the running time on one subchunk could be much longer!

With Method 2 it is possible to have the same problem.  Again, with merge sort its not clear since the running time for each subchunk is likely to be similar, but the line `//wait for thread_id[FREE_CORE] and current thread to finish` would also require one core to wait for the other.  However, with Method 2, all calls to `Merge` run ASAP as opposed to Method 1 where one must wait for `NUM_CORES` calls to `MergeSort` to finish and then do `NUM_CORES - 1` merges afterward (although you can multithread this as well...to an extent)

(though the syntax might not be completely correct)
Are both of these methods used in practice?  Are there situations where one is more beneficial over the other?  Is this the correct way to implement Method 2?  (in this case, `THREADS_IN_USE` is a semaphore?)

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your basic assumption 'threads > cores == bad' is not always true. When a thread requests I/O (socket, file, terminal) it does not use the cpu, and goes into a sort of wait state, depending on the OS. So, having lots of I/O dispatcher/readers > #cores  may not be a bad idea for I/O bound applications. The same model applies to database clients.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is good to know.  However, my real question is about best practices (algorithms) for multithreaded recursive functions.  The code for choosing the optimal number of threads to use based on the context is a separate issue that can be added in later.